# VB System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As Gecko.GeckoNavigatedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigated
    ToolStripTextBox1.Text = GeckoWebBrowser1.Url.OriginalString
    **Parent.Text = GeckoWebBrowser1.Site.Name.ToString** 
    ''GeckoWebBrowser1.DocumentTitle.ToString
    ''GeckoWebBrowser1.Site.Name.ToString()
End Sub
```

If i start program VB say me System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code on bold line.

Comment: Try to check if either Site or Name is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have it. I put timer for

> Parent.Text = GeckoWebBrowser1.Site.Name.ToString

because app wont get a site name before site loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you code to:

```
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As Gecko.GeckoNavigatedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigated
    ToolStripTextBox1.Text = GeckoWebBrowser1.Url.OriginalString
    if GeckoWebBrowser1 isnot nothing AndAlso GeckoWebBrowser1.Site isnot nothing then
    Parent.Text = GeckoWebBrowser1.Site.Name.ToString
    ''GeckoWebBrowser1.DocumentTitle.ToString
    ''GeckoWebBrowser1.Site.Name.ToString()
    end if
End Sub
```